# database table output structure change below format is explained

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Need Help in print tag wise report

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve the same effect like this?

**
The below format which is having stored in SQL database isn't able to print each user wise

**

```html
<table border="2" width="460" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;"><strong>code</strong></span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;"><strong>name</strong></span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;"><strong>ele</strong></span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div><span style="color: black;"><strong>amt</strong></span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;"><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">FAREWELL</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">50</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">FAREWELL</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GCLUB</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">50</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GENTS CLUB</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GYM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">10</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GYM FEES</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MAINT</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">50</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">HOUSE MAINT.</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MESS</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">2999</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MESS DEDUN.</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06105</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">SIVA M</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">TEA</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">20</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">TEA COUPON</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">TEA</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">249</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">TEA COUPON</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MESS</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">3936</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MESS DEDUN.</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">MAINT</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">50</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">HOUSE MAINT.</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GYM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">10</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GYM FEES</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">FAREWELL</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">50</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">FAREWELL</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="68">
        <div><span style="color: black;">M06839</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="136">
        <div><span style="color: black;">RAM VISHAK R D</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="88">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GCLUB</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="43">
        <div align="right"><span style="color: black;">30</span></div>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" nowrap="nowrap" width="123">
        <div><span style="color: black;">GENTS CLUB</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**below table  format is easy able to print

I need like out in HTML or asp.net  pivot is not working

backend used: SQL
front end: HTML , asp.net

thanks in advance coders
**

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 656px;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>CODE</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>M06105</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>Name</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>Siva M</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>FAREWELL</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>GENTS CLUB</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>GYM FEES</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>10</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>HOUSE MAINT.</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>MESS DEDUN.</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>2999</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>TEA COUPON</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>20</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 656px;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>CODE</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>M06839</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>Name</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>RAM VISHAK R D</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>FAREWELL</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>GENTS CLUB</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>GYM FEES</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>10</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>HOUSE MAINT.</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>50</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>MESS DEDUN.</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>3936</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>TEA COUPON</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>249</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 103px;">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: How to generate the first Html code?

Comment: not a html sql backend format

Comment: You should describe how this Html was generated,